# VS Community Error when trying to add references

Tags: c++, windows-10-universal, vs-community-edition

I am attempting to add references to C++ Universal Windows Application in VS Community 2015.  When I attempt to do so, I get the following error:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

[image]

What is causing this?  I have done this before and it has worked fine.  Even in this project it has worked before, but I had to remove the project and add it again, and now I cannot add the reference.  How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup minutes after posting this question I found an answer.  The problem: *the referenced project was targeting a higher version of Windows than the main project*.

#### To change target version:

Right-click on the project and click *Properties*.  Then change the *Target Platform Version* so that the referenced project has one lower or equal to the main class.